# Macbook pro 13" OSX Mavericks F3-Key Function?

Tags: macos

Whats this <kbd>F3</kbd> on the Macbook pro 13" with MacOs Mavericks on it? If I press it, there is my desktop big and above from it, my open programs with thumbnail. But this is feature is senseless, because from there I cant switch through my programs with shortcuts.

Greetings.

Comment: Ah..I see...I dont need a mouse anymore lol

Comment: Nah, you dont understand. I'm a developer and I switched from Windows + VirtualBox to Mac. Thats because I'm asking here...I dont know anything about Mac. But I see now...I press FN+F3 and can easily switch through apps with the touchpad.

Comment: I do understand. Whether you are a developer or not doesn't chagne the fact that you are asking about a  feature of OS X which is not programming specific / related.

Answer (score 1):

That is called "Mission Control"

If you prefer to use the keyboard rather than the mouse to switch to a different workspace, you can use <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd>